# When non stationarity is a problem?

Tags: machine-learning, predictive-models, stationarity

So in the literature one can find many times that ML works on the assumption that data distributions are stationary.

Now I can do multiple tests on my dataset to show the violation on the non stationarity. Many of the papers I find include time series analysis that is not my goal.
I want to use my input features without any notion of time to predict a value.

The best way to explain it is that I have features about houses and I want to predict the houses possible selling value. Some of those features, like criminal rate, are non stationary. The question is then, do I still need to care about that dataset is non stationary since I am not predicting prices over time just the "instantaneous" price of the property if it was sold in the next dt.

When do you care for non stationarity when you do not work with time series problems?

Regards,
Alex

Comment: Are you using a surrogate for time, for example sales listed in order of occurrence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You care about stationarity whenever the model you are using assumes that the data is stationary. To understand this, consider a simple MA(3) model. In it, we assume that

$$
x_t \vert x_1, \ldots,x_{t-1} \sim \mathcal{N}\left(\mu + \sum_{q=1}^3 \theta_q x_{t-q}, \sigma^2\right).
$$

That is, we are assuming that the current observation depends on past observations and a constant (mean) term $\mu$. Under these assumptions, there is no way for the model to start trending upwards or downwards indefinitely (assuming the weights offset the observations) since the current observed data $x_t$ is completely determined by its 3 preceding observations and the mean term.

Next, consider this example of a modified MA(3) model:

$$
x_t \vert x_1, \ldots,x_{t-1} \sim \mathcal{N}\left(t\cdot\mu + \sum_{q=1}^3 \theta_q x_{t-q}, \sigma^2\right).
$$

Notice that this model is **not** stationary since our mean term is always a multiple of however many time steps have passed. If $\mu >0$, then we are assuming that the model is trending upwards and if $\mu < 0$, we assume that is trending downwards.

In conclusion, you care about stationarity if you assume that the data is stationary and you want to use a model that captures it. Make sure to note which assumptions the model you want to use takes into consideration against what the data is telling you. This usually done via hypothesis testing.

Hope this helps.

Comment: "care about stationarity if you assume that the data is stationary" sound like tautology. We can modify the question as: when stationarity assumpion matters and why?

Comment: Moreover, you examples sound like AR more than MA, and the second cannot be an MA. Indeed MA are stationarity by construction.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @markowitz. Indeed, the second example is not an MA model, which is why I denoted it as a "modified MA".